# d3.json() not fetching data from JSON file

Tags: d3.js

JSON source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json

I am trying to fetch data into d3 using d3.json() but I am not getting any output when I try to log out my data to the console.

```js
d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json').then(data => console.log(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

But getting no output in the console.

I ultimately want to map the values into a new array but can't seem to get this step working properly.

I have tried using fetch and can get the object loaded into the console but not with d3.json.

Also:

When trying to push those data values to an array not getting any values returned

```
d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json')
  .then(data => data.data.forEach(ea => dataset.push(ea[0])));

console.log(dataset);
```

Comment: Look at the console in the edited SO snippet. The data is there.

Comment: Oh, maybe codepen froze on me, thank you!

Comment: Hi sorry, I've added another piece of code to the promise, why is my forEach not allowing me to push data from the promise call to an empty array?